# Como obtener los campos de una tabla teniendo replace en la consulta

Tags: sql, oracle, select, replace

Se me presenta dicha consulta, cómo obtener cada uno de los campos de una tabla sin tener que sacarlos individualmente:

Cómo los obtengo actualmente: SELECT Nombre, DNI, REPLACE(DNI, '', '') FROM TABLADATOS;

Como deseo obtenerlos (aquí marca error de sintaxis): SELECT *, REPLACE(DNI, '', '') FROM TABLADATOS;

La tabla contiene muchos mas campos, y me seria muy útil usar *

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado a utilizar un alias para la columna que retorna `Replace`?.  `SELECT *, REPLACE(DNI, '', '') AS 'col1'  FROM TABLADATOS;` [MySql Alias](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/).

Comment: Sí, pero me muestra lo siguiente: ORA-00923: palabra clave FROM no encontrada donde se esperaba @Javifer2

Comment: Has puesto una etiqueta mySql y el error que muestras es de Oracle. Revisa esta respuesta [Ora-00923](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830624/error-ora-00923-from-keyword-not-found-where-expected)

Comment: Según leo hay que emplear comillas dobles en vez de simples, lo que me sigue marcando error es esto -> *, @Javifer2

Comment: De que error estamos hablando? podrias poner un ejemplo claro?

Comment: `SELECT TABLADATOS.*, REPLACE(DNI, '', '') AS REP FROM TABLADATOS;`. Así el * corresponde a todas las columnas de la tabla. Por otro lado Replace en pl/sql puede contener un solo parámetro y no parece de mucho sentido usarlo tal cual, me supongo que es un ejemplo. [Replace](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es necesario que utilices el nombre o alias de la tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLADATOS
       (ID NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY,
        NAME VARCHAR2(14) ,
        DNI VARCHAR2(13) , 
        COL VARCHAR2(10)
       ) ;
INSERT INTO TABLADATOS
VALUES
(1,'Test1','100040-A','VAL1');
INSERT INTO TABLADATOS
VALUES
(2,'Test2','100040-B','VAL2');
```

Tal que:

```
SELECT TABLADATOS.*, REPLACE(DNI, 'A', 'Z') AS REP 
FROM TABLADATOS;
```

[image: Res1]

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1194b8/1)